# Gitlab-CE could not open setting CI/CD section. get error 500

Tags: gitlab-ci-runner, gitlab-ce

I have installed Gitlab-CE on the Ubuntu server. the info is as follows:

```
Ruby:         ruby 3.0.6p216 (2023-03-30 revision 23a532679b) [x86_64-linux]
GitLab:       16.1.2 (e60fc11f2d3) FOSS
GitLab Shell: 14.23.0
PostgreSQL:   13.11
```

The problem is when either I want to Open CI/CD section in the Admin setting or Project setting, It shows the below error:

[image]

the Gitlab-Runner has been installed on the server:

```
Version:      16.1.0
Git revision: b72e108d
Git branch:   16-1-stable
GO version:   go1.19.9
Built:        2023-06-21T21:52:30+0000
OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
```

And this is `production.log` when I wanted to open http://Server_IP:Server_PORT/android/sade/-/settings/ci_cd:

```
{
  "method": "GET",
  "path": "/android/sade/-/settings/ci_cd",
  "format": "html",
  "controller": "Projects::Settings::CiCdController",
  "action": "show",
  "status": 500,
  "time": "2023-07-09T15:10:22.007Z",
  "params": [
    { "key": "namespace_id", "value": "android" },
    { "key": "project_id", "value": "sade" }
  ],
  "correlation_id": "01H4XK8ANDM5TGZ7YPWCW4XXQ4",
  "meta.caller_id": "Projects::Settings::CiCdController#show",
  "meta.remote_ip": "192.168.10.118",
  "meta.feature_category": "continuous_integration",
  "meta.user": "root",
  "meta.user_id": 1,
  "meta.project": "android/sade",
  "meta.root_namespace": "android",
  "meta.client_id": "user/1",
  "remote_ip": "192.168.10.118",
  "user_id": 1,
  "username": "root",
  "ua": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/16.5.1 Safari/605.1.15",
  "queue_duration_s": 0.005301,
  "response_bytes": 0,
  "request_urgency": "low",
  "target_duration_s": 5,
  "gitaly_calls": 1,
  "gitaly_duration_s": 0.005268,
  "redis_calls": 22,
  "redis_allowed_cross_slot_calls": 1,
  "redis_duration_s": 0.00463,
  "redis_read_bytes": 3412,
  "redis_write_bytes": 2285,
  "redis_feature_flag_calls": 14,
  "redis_feature_flag_duration_s": 0.002336,
  "redis_feature_flag_read_bytes": 2839,
  "redis_feature_flag_write_bytes": 877,
  "redis_repository_cache_calls": 3,
  "redis_repository_cache_duration_s": 0.000753,
  "redis_repository_cache_read_bytes": 330,
  "redis_repository_cache_write_bytes": 170,
  "redis_sessions_calls": 3,
  "redis_sessions_allowed_cross_slot_calls": 1,
  "redis_sessions_duration_s": 0.001099,
  "redis_sessions_read_bytes": 243,
  "redis_sessions_write_bytes": 1081,
  "redis_shared_state_calls": 2,
  "redis_shared_state_duration_s": 0.000442,
  "redis_shared_state_write_bytes": 157,
  "db_count": 31,
  "db_write_count": 0,
  "db_cached_count": 2,
  "db_replica_count": 0,
  "db_primary_count": 31,
  "db_main_count": 26,
  "db_ci_count": 5,
  "db_main_replica_count": 0,
  "db_ci_replica_count": 0,
  "db_replica_cached_count": 0,
  "db_primary_cached_count": 2,
  "db_main_cached_count": 1,
  "db_ci_cached_count": 1,
  "db_main_replica_cached_count": 0,
  "db_ci_replica_cached_count": 0,
  "db_replica_wal_count": 0,
  "db_primary_wal_count": 0,
  "db_main_wal_count": 0,
  "db_ci_wal_count": 0,
  "db_main_replica_wal_count": 0,
  "db_ci_replica_wal_count": 0,
  "db_replica_wal_cached_count": 0,
  "db_primary_wal_cached_count": 0,
  "db_main_wal_cached_count": 0,
  "db_ci_wal_cached_count": 0,
  "db_main_replica_wal_cached_count": 0,
  "db_ci_replica_wal_cached_count": 0,
  "db_replica_duration_s": 0.0,
  "db_primary_duration_s": 0.018,
  "db_main_duration_s": 0.017,
  "db_ci_duration_s": 0.001,
  "db_main_replica_duration_s": 0.0,
  "db_ci_replica_duration_s": 0.0,
  "cpu_s": 0.116406,
  "mem_objects": 70437,
  "mem_bytes": 4655296,
  "mem_mallocs": 16126,
  "mem_total_bytes": 7472776,
  "pid": 4440,
  "worker_id": "puma_0",
  "rate_limiting_gates": [],
  "exception.class": "ActionView::Template::Error",
  "exception.message": "",
  "exception.backtrace": [
    "lib/gitlab/crypto_helper.rb:28:in `aes256_gcm_decrypt'",
    "app/models/concerns/token_authenticatable_strategies/encryption_helper.rb:18:in `decrypt_token'",
    "app/models/concerns/token_authenticatable_strategies/encrypted.rb:78:in `get_encrypted_token'",
    "app/models/concerns/token_authenticatable_strategies/encrypted.rb:113:in `token_set?'",
    "app/models/concerns/token_authenticatable_strategies/base.rb:50:in `ensure_token!'",
    "app/models/concerns/token_authenticatable.rb:54:in `block in add_authentication_token_field'",
    "app/models/project.rb:2197:in `runners_token'",
    "app/views/projects/runners/_project_runners.html.haml:11",
    "app/views/projects/runners/_settings.html.haml:5",
    "app/views/projects/settings/ci_cd/show.html.haml:49",
    "app/controllers/application_controller.rb:144:in `render'",
    "app/controllers/projects/settings/ci_cd_controller.rb:38:in `show'",
    "app/controllers/application_controller.rb:500:in `set_current_admin'",
    "lib/gitlab/session.rb:11:in `with_session'",
    "app/controllers/application_controller.rb:491:in `set_session_storage'",
    "lib/gitlab/i18n.rb:107:in `with_locale'",
    "lib/gitlab/i18n.rb:113:in `with_user_locale'",
    "app/controllers/application_controller.rb:482:in `set_locale'",
    "app/controllers/application_controller.rb:475:in `set_current_context'",
    "lib/gitlab/metrics/elasticsearch_rack_middleware.rb:16:in `call'",
    "lib/gitlab/middleware/memory_report.rb:13:in `call'",
    "lib/gitlab/middleware/speedscope.rb:13:in `call'",
    "lib/gitlab/database/load_balancing/rack_middleware.rb:23:in `call'",
    "lib/gitlab/middleware/rails_queue_duration.rb:33:in `call'",
    "lib/gitlab/metrics/rack_middleware.rb:16:in `block in call'",
    "lib/gitlab/metrics/web_transaction.rb:46:in `run'",
    "lib/gitlab/metrics/rack_middleware.rb:16:in `call'",
    "lib/gitlab/jira/middleware.rb:19:in `call'",
    "lib/gitlab/middleware/go.rb:20:in `call'",
    "lib/gitlab/etag_caching/middleware.rb:21:in `call'",
    "lib/gitlab/middleware/query_analyzer.rb:11:in `block in call'",
    "lib/gitlab/database/query_analyzer.rb:37:in `within'",
    "lib/gitlab/middleware/query_analyzer.rb:11:in `call'",
    "lib/gitlab/middleware/multipart.rb:173:in `call'",
    "lib/gitlab/middleware/read_only/controller.rb:50:in `call'",
    "lib/gitlab/middleware/read_only.rb:18:in `call'",
    "lib/gitlab/middleware/same_site_cookies.rb:27:in `call'",
    "lib/gitlab/middleware/basic_health_check.rb:25:in `call'",
    "lib/gitlab/middleware/handle_malformed_strings.rb:21:in `call'",
    "lib/gitlab/middleware/handle_ip_spoof_attack_error.rb:25:in `call'",
    "lib/gitlab/middleware/request_context.rb:15:in `call'",
    "lib/gitlab/middleware/webhook_recursion_detection.rb:15:in `call'",
    "config/initializers/fix_local_cache_middleware.rb:11:in `call'",
    "lib/gitlab/middleware/compressed_json.rb:44:in `call'",
    "lib/gitlab/middleware/rack_multipart_tempfile_factory.rb:19:in `call'",
    "lib/gitlab/middleware/sidekiq_web_static.rb:20:in `call'",
    "lib/gitlab/metrics/requests_rack_middleware.rb:79:in `call'",
    "lib/gitlab/middleware/release_env.rb:13:in `call'"
  ],
  "exception.cause_class": "OpenSSL::Cipher::CipherError",
  "db_duration_s": 0.01585,
  "view_duration_s": 0.0,
  "duration_s": 0.11644
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error in version 16.2.3-ce.0.

After running gitlab-rake db:migrate:status and gitlab-ctl reconfigure, everything worked fine.

I then upgraded to 16.2.4-ce.0 and it's working as expected

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Just try to execute the below command on your gitlab server:

**sudo gitlab-rails c**

**settings = ApplicationSetting.last**

**settings.update_column(:runners_registration_token_encrypted, nil)**